# Nginx Autoindex giving me a 403

Tags: nginx, config, http-status-code-403

I recently set up an Nginx web server and am trying to make the directory show. After research I found that the `autoindex on;` option. Even after doing so, I was still receiving 403 errors when I tried to access the /test/ directory. I'm not sure if I'm just being dumb or if this is actually an issue.

Here is my server{} config bits

```
server{
    location /{
            index index.html;
            autoindex on;
    }
    location /test{
            autoindex on;
    }
}
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually there is Serverfault maybe is better place for such questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look at:

1. `root` directive for server or for locations
2. permissions for actual folders in file system. Its must be 755 for
   folders and 644 for files
3. I'm not sure but it is also possible conflict between `index` and
   `autoindex` directives.

Comment: I was able to change my file permissions using my FTP client filezilla. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this (with added trailing slash):

```
location /test/ {
        autoindex on;
}
```